# Different fonts in QGIS2threejs

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I'm working with QGIS2threejs for quite a while and it is a great tool!
Changing font for the 3D presentation is easy, just change it in the css file.
But here is my question:
Is it possible to change the font for each layer separatly?
Do I have to add a certain attribute in the js file, which contains all the data and adapt the css.

Any experiences here?

Help would be really great!