# Changing font in QGIS2threejs

Tags: font, qgis2threejs

In QGIS2threejs,I want to change the fonts in 3D presentation.I learned that I can do it by change it in the css file through
 [Different fonts in QGIS2threejs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282533/different-fonts-in-qgis2threejs.But) when I change the color and font,it doesn't work,the color and font doesn't change in 3D presentation. 
[image: the default setting]

[image: The setting I want to change]

Comment: Look at this thread on twitter https://twitter.com/charley_glynn/status/846758814544285697

Comment: Aha,it works by adding some lines in the HTML files.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the help @ Fran Raga,I add some lines in the HTML fils.It works,it also change the font color.[image]